# Bibtex file not referencing properly

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

My file here below has issues with referencing and do not know the problem is:
Check this link to see output:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7jsnjvdwcaabyy2/small.pdf?dl=0

```
\documentclass[titlepage, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry} %set page margins
\geometry{left=1.5in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in}
\usepackage{afterpage}

\usepackage{setspace} %set line spacing 
\doublespacing
\usepackage{ragged2e} %control centering and justifying

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %set page numbering style

\usepackage{booktabs} %set table format
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\usepackage{float} %set graphics format
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{amsmath} %allow use of math text
\usepackage{apacite}  %I added this for references
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{units}

\usepackage{listings} %allows for R code 

\usepackage{color, soul} %allows to highlight text when editing 

\usepackage{cite} %establish citation connection

\usepackage{blindtext} %allow dummy text for template





\begin{document}


\section{}

I am trying to make my citations work \cite{albert2014}
\centering
\renewcommand{\refname}{\normalsize \normalfont LIST OF REFERENCES}

%\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{refff}


%Section 14.

\newpage \pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{17} \newgeometry{left=1.5in, right=1in, top=2in, bottom=1in} \afterpage{\aftergroup \restoregeometry} \doublespacing \centering

APPENDIX A

APPENDIX A TITLE

%Section 15.

\newpage \pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{18} \newgeometry{left=1.5in, right=1in, top=2in, bottom=1in} \afterpage{\aftergroup \restoregeometry} \doublespacing \centering

APPENDIX B

APPENDIX B TITLE

\end{document}
```

`refff.bib`

```
@article{albert2014,
  title={Estimating overall exposure effects for zero-inflated regression models with application to dental caries},
  author={Albert, J.M. and Wang, W. and Nelson, S.},
  journal={Statistical Methods in Medical Research},
  volume={23},
  number={3},
  page={257--278},
  doi={{10.1177/0962280211407800}},
  year={2014},
  publisher={SAGE Publications}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: What is the problem here? You posted a huge chunk of badly formatted code and ask: "Can some one create any bib file and run it to make it work well for me." I am afraid, I cannot do that. But you could format the code, make it minimal, add a bibliography, and try to describe the problems you are having. How do you compile it, which errors do you get?

Comment: I made changes to it can you take a look at it again, please !

Comment: Did you run pdflatex twice after bibtex? → http://www.bibtex.org/Using/